# Object.keys(data) Js fu not worked when pass Json object as def in Karate 0.9.5.RC5

Tags: karate

1. Js File with following function

```
function fn(config) {

 config.OAuth2 = function (data) {
   var keys = Object.keys(data);
   return keys;
 }
 return config;
}
```

2. Feature file with following steps

```
   Feature: Sample Feature

    Scenario Outline: Sample Scenario

    #This is works
    * def a = OAuth2({firstName: '<firstName>',lastName: '<lastName>'})
    * print a

    #This do not work
    And def req = {firstName: '<firstName>',lastName: '<lastName>'}
    * def b = OAuth2(req)
    * print b

    Examples:
      | firstName | lastName |
      | a         | a1       |
```

3. Giving error at     var keys = Object.keys(data);

```
javascript evaluation failed: OAuth2(req), TypeError: {firstName=a, lastName=a1} is not an Object in <eval>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use `Object.keys()` - use [`karate.keysOf()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-keysof) instead.

Comment: karate.keysOf() worked , but why ```* def a = OAuth2({firstName: '<firstName>',lastName: '<lastName>'})``` worked with Object.keys()?

Comment: ha ha .. sure. so you mean when pass as  ```def req = {firstName: '<firstName>',lastName: '<lastName>'}``` its convert to Java (Map) but when pass as   ```OAuth2({firstName: '<firstName>',lastName: '<lastName>'})``` its Json Object